# Alpha blending on int colors exceeds byte ranges

Tags: c#, math, graphics, rounding-error

I have implemented an algorithm for alpha blending. It worked for some time, but soon I have noticed that I'm receiving some weird results in some specific cases.

I have investigated and it turned out that the algorithm yields color values larger than 255. I wrote an application to check, which combinations of color/alpha source/destination values causes the problem:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
            parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16;

            Parallel.For(0, 256, parallelOptions, bA =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"bA: {bA}...");

                for (int tA = 0; tA < 256; tA++)
                {
                    for (int bR = 0; bR < 256; bR++)
                        for (int tR = 0; tR < 256; tR++)
                        {
                            int a = (((bA + tA) * 255) - tA * bA) / 255;
                            if (a > 0)
                            {
                                var R = ((255u - tA) * bA * bR / 255 + tA * tR) / a;
                                if (R > 255)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"{bA}, {bR}, {tA}, {tR} => {R}");
                                }
                            }
                         }
                }
            });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

The results are upright scary, for instance (bA = base alpha, bR = base red, tA = target alpha, tR = target red):

```
bA, bR, tA,  tR => R
 1, 58,  1, 255 => 312
```

What is interesting is that when one replaces int with float arithmetic then results never exceed 256 (they do exceed 255, but I guess because floating point arithmetic problems).

I tried to convert the formulas in such way that the division (which seems to be the first suspect for rounding errors) is always in the end of the calculations, but that didn't help too much - I always ended up getting results exceeding 255.

Why is that? Is there a way I can fix the formulas so that I won't receive values exceeding 255?

Comment: To properly interpolate ints, use floats. Then cast the final value back to int.

Comment: Yup. I used floats in the beginning. I switched to int calculations, because floats are simply too slow...

Comment: That sounds... unlikely. But to illustrate why you _need_ floats, remember that integer division is _not_ regular division. For example, `(((bA + tA) * 255) - tA * bA) / 255` with your example values would be `(((1 + 1) * 255) - 1 * 1) / 255 = ((2*255) - 1) / 255 = 509/255` and while that would normally be "almost 2", you're using int division. Instead of 1.996, that's now 1. It might help if you explain why you wrote the code that you wrote: what is each supposed to do?